# Qlist<QCameraInfo> causes access violation in QList destructor

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I am writing a video grabbing application in c++ using Qt5. I am following their example code and looking at the documentation for getting the camera info:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamerainfo.html

The problem I have is that after I use the prescribed technique for getting camera data (which works perfectly):

```
QList<QCameraInfo>cameraInfos = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
```

I get an `Access violation` error whenever `cameraInfos` goes out of scope.

For example, if I do:

```
void readDeviceInfo(void) {

    // Camera devices:
    QList<QCameraInfo>cameraInfos = QCameraInfo::availableCameras()
    for (QList<QCameraInfo>::Iterator it = cameraInfos.begin();
    it != cameraInfos.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->description().toStdString().c_str() << std::endl; 


}
```

The crash occurs on the return of this function. If I do:

```
foreach(const QCameraInfo &ci, QCameraInfo::availableCameras());
```

The crash occurs in the evaluation of the foreach loop. Likewise, if I declare `QList<QCameraInfo> cameraInfos` as a field in a class, the crash happens when the class is destroyed. This is verified by the output of my call stack:

```
    ntdll.dll!000000007750eef1()    Unknown
    kernel32.dll!00000000773c1a0a() Unknown
>   VideoCapture.exe!free(void * pBlock) Line 51    C
    VideoCapture.exe!QCameraInfo::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    C++
    VideoCapture.exe!QList<QCameraInfo>::node_destruct(QList<QCameraInfo>::Node * from, QList<QCameraInfo>::Node * to) Line 484 C++
    VideoCapture.exe!QList<QCameraInfo>::dealloc(QListData::Data * data) Line 857   C++
    VideoCapture.exe!QList<QCameraInfo>::~QList<QCameraInfo>() Line 817 C++
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (windows obviously).

Comment: do you have `QApplication` instantiated?

Comment: Yes. The main application is a parent to this window. The idea is to instantiate a videopanle object when a button is pressed in the mainwindow part of the gui. You are probably correct that videopanel is missing some infrastructure. I'm not quite clear on the correct way to add it in.

Comment: As you can see, the base class for this is a QWidget (which doesn't have an exec() method, I notice). Should this be something else maybe?

Comment: Error seems t obe with environment, it's hard to guess what's exactly missing. Try to create `QList<int>`, will it crash? Also run your minimum code in main and see if it works

Comment: @Alexey Thanks for the excellent suggestions! Unfortunately, QList<int> works fine. I tried creating the QList<cameraInfo> in main and I get the same crash on exit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile Qt yourself, then run your test case under a debugger and see where it crashes. You also need a minimal, self-contained test case for this - and that must be the part of the question ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).  As it is, it's more likely that you're corrupting memory elsewhere and the failure you're seeing is the outcome of a corrupted heap, not a Qt bug.

Sidebar: You need to be proficient in running small examples in Qt Creator. Arguably, the templates Qt Creator comes with aren't very good for that. You can [use this template](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/qtcreator-templates), available as Other Projects->Simple qmake, to make quick prototypes.

The following works fine for me with 1 camera on current Qt on both OS X 10.9 and Windows 10/VS 2015. The `std::cout` you're using is red herring, you can use `qDebug()` as well.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/camlist-37603946
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QComboBox combo;
   QObject::connect(&combo, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [&]{
      std::cout << combo.currentText().toStdString() << std::endl;
   });
   for (auto const & info : QCameraInfo::availableCameras())
      combo.addItem(info.description());
   combo.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Than you for this. I have stripped away all the code but main and copied your example in. I am getting the same error on the release of the QList<CameraInfo> object. I am also getting the same pointer problem when I print out the contents of the combo box that I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669003/c-qt-combobox-currenttext-tostdstr-returns-huge-amount-of-data  . You are probably right that these two questions are one and the same. I am using the Qt 5 for VS 2013 pre built binary. I will try building my own and seeing what happens.

Comment: I should say that my ignorance of C++ is such that I don't know how to get any more information out the debugger than what I've already reported here.

Answer (score 0):

So after following Kuba's advice and running his test program in my environment with a freshly built Qt library, I got the same errors. Then I had the bright idea to run it in `release` mode rather than `debug`. Lo and behold, it worked perfectly, with both the freshly built Qt5 (x86, as it happened) and the pre-built binaries (64 bit) gotten from Qt's downloads page.

It seems that linking to the qt `debug` libraries was causing this behavior. I'm now linking to the non-debug libraries in debug mode and am nice and happy -- for the most part -- I am still a little annoyed that the qt libs suffixed with 'd' don't seem to work properly on my system. Nevertheless, I can move on with developing this project.

Thanks to all that commented and answered!