# qt c++ mysterious incomplete class type error on ui

Tags: c++, qt

I set up the skeleton for a multi-window qt project. It compiled ans was looking good, so I started adding all my gui elements and such. Now, all of a sudden, one of my windows is broken. Particularly, I'm having some trouble with this part in the header

```
namespace Ui {
class VideoPanel;
} ...

private:

    Ui::VideoPanel *ui;
```

and the corresponding part in the cpp file:

```
VideoPanel::VideoPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VideoPanel)

{
    ui->setupUi(this); //

}
```

The error I get is

```
Error   1   error C2512: 'Ui::VideoPanel' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

on the line `ui(new Ui::VideoPanel)`.

I have seen that if you don't include all the correct Qt gui headers, this can happen, so I've stripped everything out of my code except for the constructor and the destructor.

full h:

```
#ifndef VIDEOPANEL_H
#define VIDEOPANEL_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class VideoPanel;
}

class VideoPanel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VideoPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~VideoPanel();

private slots:

private:

    Ui::VideoPanel *ui;

};

#endif // VIDEOPANEL_H
```

full cpp:

```
#include "videopanel.h"
#include "ui_videopanel.h"

VideoPanel::VideoPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VideoPanel)

{
    ui->setupUi(this); // 

}

VideoPanel::~VideoPanel()
{

}
```

Comment: this tells me that `Ui::VideoPanel` doesn't have a default constructor

Comment: Why are you only putting a forward declare in the namespace instead of the actual class code?

Comment: That's the Qt yoga. See any of their examples. The headers always have that forward declare.

Comment: you are including `"ui_videopanel.h"` which contains the definition for `Ui::VideoPanel` class. have you tried cleaning the project and re-building??

Comment: Yes I did. What's weird is that this problem arose when I changed the name of the class from videoPanel to VideoPanel. When I go back to the original spelling, it works again. I am running MOC on videopanel.h and UIC on my form file on the clean/build cycle.

Comment: I think that you should have mentioned that the error occurred after you changed the name of your class in the `.cpp`, `.h` files.

Comment: @dmedine *That's the Qt yoga. See any of their examples* Can you point one out? Never seen that.

Answer (score 2):

you changed the name of your class, but the `.ui` file seems to have the old name in its `<class>` tag. you have to change the name there in order to have UIC generate a header file that is compatible with your new name.

To do so if you are using Qt Creator, you can open your `ui` file in the designer, and change the `objectName` property to your new class name, you may have to do a clean build after that.
[image]

Comment: Nice! Now can you tell me why my program crashes when I release a QList<QCameraInfo> object from that widget? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603946/qlistqcamerainfo-causes-access-violation-in-qlist-destructor